# Write a sql to pivot a table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I would like to create something like this

Input Data table

```
customer_id fee_name    amount
1   a   1
1   b   3.25
1   c   1.75
1   d   2
1   e   0
2   a   1
2   b   3.25
2   c   1.75
2   d   2
2   e   0
3   a   1
3   b   3.25
3   c   1.75
3   d   3.5
3   e   0
4   a   1
4   b   3.25
4   c   1.75
4   d   3.5
4   f   1
5   a   1
5   b   3.25
5   c   1.75
5   d   3.5
5   f   1
```

See, you have to create groups for all fee_name and amount. So there would be 3 groups here. 1 resembling the schedule for customer 1 and 2, second group resembling customer 3 and the third group resembling schedule for customers 4 and 5. name this groups also

Output 1 should look like

```
group  a  b     c     d    e  f
    1  1  3.25  1.75  2 0  0
    2  1  3.25  1.75  3.5  0  0
    3  1  3.25  1.75  3.5  0  1
```

Second output table should map these groups to customer id.
So second output should look like

```
customer id group
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   3
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: Please tag properly.  It's either MySQL or SQL Server, can't be both.  Also, where's your query attempt?

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: Then remove sql-server tag.

Comment: Have you Googled it?  There are tons of info about how to do pivot table in MySQL.

Comment: Read this: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Hi eric, if you have read the problem, it's not just about pivoting. There are more manipulations required

Comment: If you were to group by fee and amount, there would be 6 groups.

Comment: I think there would be 3 only, there are only 5 groups available as there are only 5 customer_id's and customer 1 and 2 have same group, and customer 4 and 5 have same group. Hence, total unique groups in this dataset is 5-2=3

Comment: I see - it's the three fee schedules - as would be given by this query... `SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(amount ORDER BY fee_name) fee_schedule FROM my_table GROUP BY customer_id;`

Comment: Code to generate pivot code:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.customer_id
     , CASE WHEN @prev = x.fee_schedule THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
     , @prev:=x.fee_schedule 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(amount ORDER BY fee_name) fee_schedule FROM my_table GROUP BY customer_id ) x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT customer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(amount ORDER BY fee_name) fee_schedule FROM my_table GROUP BY customer_id ) y
    ON y.fee_schedule = x.fee_schedule
  JOIN
     ( SELECT @prev:=null, @i:=0 ) vars
 ORDER 
    BY y.fee_schedule
     , y.customer_id;
```